# SQL docs matching names recursively

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a document table with a recursive tree structure using self referencing.

```
Table Docs
------------
id
parentId -- parent Docs' id
name
isFile -- is this entry a file?
...
```

where the root folder has `parentId = null`.

Now, I would like to create a SQL query that fetches the docs recursively where the name matches (`%.ending1`, `%.ending2`)

My attempts have lead me to this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE DocsRecursive AS (
  SELECT "id", "parentId", "name"
  FROM "Docs"
  WHERE id = <seed-id>
UNION ALL
  SELECT child."id", child."parentId", child."name"
  FROM "Docs" AS child
  JOIN DocsRecursive AS parent ON parent.id = child."parentId" AND 
    (
      child."name" LIKE '%.ending1' OR
      child."name" LIKE '%.ending2'
    )      
)
SELECT * FROM DocsRecursive
```

The issue with this is that it will only returns direct child docs where the name matches the intended endings. Because if the direct childs are not matching the names (as they wont, as they are then folders), they are not traversed further.

Is it possible to traverse the whole tree, but only return the docs where the name matches my endings?

Comment: Is there anything in your schema that differentiates files from folders?

Comment: Yes. Edited the question to include the parameter.